# SpriteKit correct asset size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcasset

### Summary

I'm creating an SpriteKit game for different devices and I'm wondering what should be the size of the different assets.

### What I have right now

I'm creating the `SKScene` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

I don't want to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` because it is called twice on start up and also each time the device is rotated. I don't think that initialising the scene here is a good idea.

With this configuration, my view is initialised with a width of 600 points (default storyboard size) and then rescaled to the device width. Using `println(scene.size.width)` after the view has been layout it displays a 375 points size in the iPhone 6 and 414 points in the iPhone 6 Plus.

I'm using xcassets to provide the background images and I would like to know which sizes should I use. My current configuration is ready for 320 points resolutions (iPhone 4, iPhone 5)

- **1x**: 320 pixels
- **2x**: 640 pixels
- **3x**: 960 pixels

### The problem

The problem is that the image will be rescaled in following devices:

- **iPhone 6**: 750 pixels - 375 points
- **iPhone 6 Plus**: 1242 pixels - 414 points
- **iPad**: 768 pixels - 768 points
- **iPad retina**: 1536 pixels - 768 points

I would like to know how am I supposed to configure the images and the SKScene size to optimise it for all the devices.

Comment: viewwilllayout is the recommended way, just check self.view == nil before presenting the scene

Comment: also check scene scaleMode

Comment: I've already tried it and it initialises it at 600 pixels width in the first call and then to the correct 750 (iPhone 6) width. If I check that the scene is nil, it will be initialised at 600 pixels width, the same as in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I can do it correctly in the first call of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (Notice the **Did** instead of **Will**) Do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to initialize scene twice you can initialize it only once:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];


    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    skView.showsDrawCount = YES;
    skView.showsPhysics = YES;
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    if(!skView.scene){
    // Create and configure the scene.
        GameScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a project I'm currently working on, I decided to make my assets in the largest possible resolution, i.e. the one of the iPhone 6 Plus (2208 x 1242, [iOS Resolution Reference](http://www.iosres.com/)). Since iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 use a 16:9 aspect ratio, it is no problem to down-scale the assets implicitly with

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
```

On iPad and iPhone 4s, this will result in a border, but I can live with that.